# Treating each record in a table, using all DOM manipulating functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I try  to loop through each records in a table, using the following function. It does perfectly work. But the problem is that i only can use html() function. Other DOM manipulating functions of jquery such as text(), val() or attr() don't give any result. What is wrong here?

```
 $("#mprDetailDataTable tr:gt(0)").each(function () {
    var this_row = $(this); //select the row
    var record1= $.trim(this_row.find('td:eq(0)').html());//td:eq(0) means first td of this row
    var record2= $.trim(this_row.find('td:eq(1)').html());
    var record3= $.trim(this_row.find('td:eq(2)').html());
});
```

Comment: Try this `$('#mprDetailDataTable tr:gt(0)').each(function(index,item){ var thisRow=$(item);  });`

Comment: Are any of the elements hidden?  Here is a fiddle that works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/rcv0j7uL/1/